# How to get regex to fail if more than 4 pipe characters

Tags: php, regex

I am stuck on a regex expression. I have a string which should begin with several values separated by 4 pipe `|` characters. All I want the regex to do is let me know if there are less or more pipes. The regex works if there are less than 4 pipes, but continues to give a positive when there are more, even though I think I have what I need to basically say, "no more pipes the rest of the way."

I'm expecting the following example to fail, but it still returns true:

```
$string = 'a|b|c|d|e|f';

if (preg_match('/^.*\|.*\|.*\|.*\|[^\|]+$/u', $string)) {
    echo 'Four pipes at beginning';
}
else {
    echo 'not enough or too many pipes';
}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `.*`s with `[^|]*`s:

```
$string = 'a|b|c|d|e|f';

if (preg_match('/^[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^|]*\|[^\|]*$/u', $string)) {
    echo 'Four pipes at beginning';
}
else {
    echo 'not enough or too many pipes';
}
```

Your last one is right, but the first four `.*`s will match strings that include a pipe symbol.  Note that the `+` at the end of your original regex *requires* a character at the end.  If you really only want to check the number of pipes, you should use `*` instead.

Comment: Considering we don't know what kind of data is supposed to be in the string, your example is perfect in my opinion. If specific characters / types are used, then just replace `[^|]` with whatever characters are needed.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fail because you use .* which matches every character.
Try this instead:

```
/^([a-z])\|([a-z])\|([a-z])\|([a-z])\$/u
```